# Regular Expression with only limited special character

Tags: regex

I want to create Regular expression which should match with following criteria -

1. Min length 2
2. should accept **a-z A-Z 0-9 spaces** and special characters **- . / #** only.
3. should not start and end with spaces.In between spaces are allowed.

I tried but not able to get success -

```
/^[^\s][A-Za-z0-9-#.\/\s][^\s]$/
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide test examples that you expect to match and to not match?

Comment: Hey, are you sure regex is the only solution for this? This could easily be done using a programming language or excel functions

Comment: @Vitim.us  should accept  "abE #f . / 90d" but not accept " sD D@@ "because it starts with space and contains @.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[^\s]` will allow *any* non-whitespace character, not just the ones that are in your limited set. You need to list the characters you allow there, not just the characters you don't allow. This is the same as what you allow in the middle, except without `\s`.

You also need `*` after the middle part to allow any number of those characters.

```
/^[A-Za-z0-9-#.\/][A-Za-z0-9-#.\/\s]*[A-Za-z0-9-#.\/]$/
```

Answer (score 1):

Try Regex: `^[a-zA-Z0-9\.\/#-][a-zA-Z0-9\.\/# -]*[a-zA-Z0-9\.\/#-]$`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZshNnm/1)

Comment: How is this different from previously posted answer mate ?

Comment: Thanks Matt. G 
@ Code Maniac both submitted almost simultaneously :)

Comment: @CodeManiac, didn't notice. fine with deleting it

Comment: @Matt.G better i suggest to add some explanation to your answer and make it more readable so it will be helpful for future readers